# Multiple cab installer for Windows Mobile with CE kernel in lazarus

Tags: windows-ce, cab, lazarus

Spending more than an hour on figuring out if an equivalent solution to the problem of Multiple CAB installer exists for Windows Mobile in the lazarus cross-platfor compiler I have become tired? I mean the code that represents roughly the same functionality as:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65319/Automatically-Install-Multiple-CAB-Files-to-a-Wind

but as far as I can say it is not possible by interior inf declaration, nor by:

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/WinCE_Programming_Tips#Installation_of_an_app_build_with_Lazarus_on_a_WinCE_device

Do you know any solution to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two concepts with one.  The first link describes how to use ActiveSync's deployment architecture to deploy multiple CAB files *from the PC* serially.  One CAB file is pushed down to the device and extracted, then the next is pushed down and extracted.  This is done by hooking into the extensibility for a desktop MSI file and Windows installer.

This should work fine for any set of CABs - Lazarus or not.  To this system a CAB file is a CAB file, the contents are not relevant.

The second link is a description of an INF file (among other thigs).  This is an *input* file for CABWIZ.exe, which is a desktop tool that simply generates CAB files that can be used on a WinMo/WinCE device.  even if you generate a CAB that contains another CAB with CABWIZ, the device side of things (wceload.exe) does not support extracting a CAb within a CAB.

It's a fundamental limitation that you can't avoid.  To make things worse, newer versions of WinMo can't have two instances of wceload running, so you can't launch (via a custom installer DLL) a second instance of WCELOAD to extract an internal CAB.

You best solution is to not try.  Just extract *everything* for your app on your PC - app, references, resources - everything.  Then create an INF to package it *all* into one CAB (not a CAB inside a CAB) and then deploy that CAB.